# How to include dynamically added input values inside a .each() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a system where by a user can create or edit a game, and sometimes the user may need to increase the number of "maximum players" each game can have. When the screen is initially loaded, the system provides the user with the corresponding number of inputs that game already has. So if a game has a maximum player number of 3, it will display 3 text inputs.

Sometimes the user may need to increase the "maximum players" number of a game that's already saved. So if the original game has 3 maximum players, and this is then increased to 5 maximum players, the system will automatically add 2 new text inputs to the screen.

When the user has finished, then will click the "Save" button and the system will look for each input based on it's class. For the below example it's looking for two classes, `er-offpeak-2` and `er-peak-2`, and it will group all of the `er-offpeak-2` clases together, and all of the `er-peak-2` classes together. All of the values that are then found are appended to a string which is then saved to the database. At the moment the HTML looks like this when the original 3 inputs are displayed:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;">
            <td><input type="text" value="3" id="er-maxplayer-2" class="maxplayerinput" data-gameid="2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="2">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my HTML after the maximum players are increased to 5:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;">
            <td><input type="text" value="5" id="er-maxplayer-2" class="maxplayerinput" data-gameid="2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="2">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="2">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-maxpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="1.00" class="er-offpeak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editrow-2 er-container" style="display:none;" data-minpinc="0">
            <td><input type="text" value="2.00" class="er-peak-2"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the JQuery code that I have that is looking for all of these classes, and then grouping them together:

```
var offPeaks = '';
var peaks = '';

$('.er-offpeak-2').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() !== 'N/A') {
        var optionSelected = $(this).val()+'/';
        offPeaks += optionSelected;
    }
});

$('.er-peak-2').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() !== 'N/A') {
        var optionSelected = $(this).val()+'/';
        peaks += optionSelected;
    }
});
```

My problem at the moment is that the above JQuery code only seems to be able to see the inputs that were created when the page was loaded and doesn't include the inputs that were added dynamically to the table.

What can I do to include the dynamically added inputs?

Comment: Is this jQuery code inside "save" button `click` handler, or what?

Comment: The JQuery code is inside a click function. So there is a button that is clicked and will trigger the above code.

Comment: It does work for me just fine if I put your code inside "save" button `click` handler... [See JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hhfsnjkm/)

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the table. For instance

```
<table id="players">
```

Than in jQuery trigger if anything changes

```
$("#players").change (function() {
  var offPeaks = '';
  var peaks = '';

  $('.er-offpeak-2').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() !== 'N/A') {
      var optionSelected = $(this).val()+'/';
      offPeaks += optionSelected;
    }
  });

  $('.er-peak-2').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() !== 'N/A') {
      var optionSelected = $(this).val()+'/';
      peaks += optionSelected;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't seem to do anything.